# How to add multiple category in product laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, web

I need to store my product in multiple categories. i.e I can choose multiple categories and the items will be stored under these all categories.

I am confused about how can i achieve that. I think i have two options

1. Add the product two times with different categgory_id
2. Add category_id in array format or something(i am not sure)

please help me how can I do that

i tried by writing but didn't worked

```
foreach($response->category_id as $category_id){
   $product->category_id = $category_id;
   $product-save();
}
```

Form for that

```
<div class="form-group row" id="category">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-from-label">{{translate('Category')}} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select multiple class="form-control aiz-selectpicker" name="category_id" id="category_id" data-live-search="true" required>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->getTranslation('name') }}</option>
            @foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory)
            @include('categories.child_category', ['child_category' => $childCategory])
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    

    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->added_by = $request->added_by;
  
    $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
    $product->barcode = $request->barcode;

    $product->save();

    //VAT & Tax
    if($request->tax_id) {
        foreach ($request->tax_id as $key => $val) {
            $product_tax = new ProductTax;
            $product_tax->tax_id = $val;
            $product_tax->product_id = $product->id;
            $product_tax->tax = $request->tax[$key];
            $product_tax->tax_type = $request->tax_type[$key];
            $product_tax->save();
        }
    }
    //Flash Deal
    if($request->flash_deal_id) {
        $flash_deal_product = new FlashDealProduct;
        $flash_deal_product->flash_deal_id = $request->flash_deal_id;
        $flash_deal_product->product_id = $product->id;
        $flash_deal_product->save();
    }

  enter image description here  
    //combinations start
    $options = array();
    if($request->has('colors_active') && $request->has('colors') && count($request->colors) > 0) {
        $colors_active = 1;
        array_push($options, $request->colors);
    }

    if($request->has('choice_no')){
        foreach ($request->choice_no as $key => $no) {
            $name = 'choice_options_'.$no;
            $data = array();
            foreach ($request[$name] as $key => $eachValue) {
                array_push($data, $eachValue);
            }
            array_push($options, $data);
        }
    }

    $product->save();

    flash(translate('Product has been inserted successfully'))->success();

    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should make a many-to-many relation between products and categories

Answer (score 3):

You probaby also have a `categories` table with something like `[id,title]` columns. If you can have multiple products in a category, and categories for each product, then it's a Many-To-Many relationship. (See the laravel docs at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

1. Add a pivot table in your database named `category_product` with columns `[product_id, category_id]`. You can create a migration to do this (See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#generating-migrations on how to do this).
2. Add the relationships in your `Product` and `Category` models. In your product model,

   public function categories()
   {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
   }

And in your category model:

```
public function products()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Note: If you name your pivot table anything other than `category_product` (alphabetical) then you can pass the table name as a second parameter. e.g. `$this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'mypivottable');`

This table maps any products to any categories. If product with ID 42 has categories with IDs 3 and 4, then you'll have 2 entries in your pivot table: [product_id=42, category_id=3] and [product_id=42, category_id=4].

3. Laravel will handle pretty much everything else automatically. If you call `$product->categories()` then it will return an Eloquent `Builder` to query further on the categories that `$product` is attached to. If you use `$product->categories` as a 'magic' attribute, it will return a `Collection` of categories that had their ids in a row matching the `product_id`. The reverse will work for a category. To get a `Collection` of products in a `$category`, just use `$category->products`, or call `$category->products()->where(...)` to query further on the products in the pivot table that have a row with the matching `category_id`.
4. To save a new product,

   $product = new Product();
   // ...
   $product->save();

   $product->categories()->attach( $arrayOfCategoryIds );
   // This last line saves the rows in the pivot table

There are more methods listed in the docs for detaching or updating the relationship on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't  get that, can you please simplify it. I am new to laravel

Comment: I added more info, but the best way is to read the docs at the links I gave. They explain it all pretty well. Start with creating the new `category_product` table in your DB with `category_id` and `product_id` columns.

Comment: Currently i have return $this->hasMany(Product::class);  in product function should i replace it with belongstomany

Comment: $product->categories()->attach( $arrayOfCategoryIds ); when i added this line it shows error 500

Comment: If you added a pivot table, then yes, use BelongsToMany.

Comment: If you set up the BelongsToMany relationship correctly, then that line will work. (And ‘$arrayOfCategoryIds’ is an array of category ids for $product)